# Receiving "Duplicate enty for primary key"

Tags: c#, mysql, model-view-controller, duplicates

Using  MVC 2 , MySQL

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {          
        string name = Request.Form["name"];
        string password = Request.Form["password"];

        ViewData["name"] = name;
        ViewData["password"] = password;
        // Pasa los datos al ViewData, hace el insert
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_alumnos(Nombre, Apellido) values('"+name+"','"+password+"')", cn);
        try
        {
            // Intenta conectarse e insertar los datos
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return View("~/Views/Inicial/Inicial.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // si no puede, error
            ViewData["ex"] = ex;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

This is my code from the controller
And my error code is:

> Lo sentimos; se produjo un error al procesar la solicitud. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at MvcApplication1.Controllers.ValidarController.Register() in E:\Proyecto\TestsDByAjax\MvcApplication1\Controllers\ValidarController.cs:line 61

Line 61 says `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: First, please don't store passwords in cleartext. This application might only be something you're learning with and may never make it into production, but break that very bad habit fast. Second, sanitize your inputs. Use parameters rather than creating SQL statements by concatenation so you avoid SQL injection. Finally, I'm guessing that `Nombre` is your primary key and as such you're trying to insert a duplicate, hence the error message to that effect.

Comment: Yes, this is a test application, umm, I have a primary Key called DNI, not Nombre

Comment: Are you putting a value in `DNI`? A unique one for each record?

Comment: What is the mechanism of generating primary key?

Comment: No, im not putting any value to DNI, and I have it as NOT NULL on the database, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: There is no mechanism, should the users insert DNI for this to work?

Comment: Post the DDL for your table. You have no identity insert on your DNI?

Comment: Thanks alot guys! Bob Kaufman helped me understand I had to create a DNI for each person! Thanks, by the way, how can I tick you for a good answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, I have an answer already what is wrong, I just don't know what you want to do with it?

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_alumnos(Nombre, Apellido) values('"+name+"','"+password+"')"
```

In the statement above you inserting name and password into table. And you claiming that another field, namely `DNI` is the primary key on the table. You obviously don't insert anything into `DNI`. If the field `DNI` had identity insert you wouldn't have issue with the statement above. But you probably don't and this is why it complaining. So, if you would supply unique `DNI`, you would be OK

Comment: "INSERT INTO tbl_alumnos(DNI, Nombre, Apellido) values('"+DNI+"','"+name+"','"+password+"')" // did this since DNI is the primary key and needed to have a value! :)

Comment: Yes @MiGu3X But in modern systems, more and more, you see identity seed as PK value and unique key on some special field. For example, `pkUsers, userName`. `pkUsers` would be used for joins. For example, in table `Log` you would have field `LoggedBy`. `LoggedBy` would be foreign key to `pkUsers`. This field would have auto-generated sequential number in it like 1,2,3... While `userName` will have unique key applied so no two users will have same name. And it will not be used in joins, only in `Where` clause. The point here-you may let system create your PK if you can. Then, statement w/o DNI w